# python (arcpy) windows scheduled task

Tags: python, scheduled-tasks, arcgis, arcpy

I am trying to setup a windows scheduled task to run a python script that runs various `arcpy` tools. The script works in a scheduled task except for when I'm running the initial `arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion` conversion of a shapefile or a table into a feature class/table in a geodatabase.

```
import os
import arcpy
import arceditor
import sys
import datetime

J_GT_SURVEYS = (r"J:\\Ground_Truth_Surveys\\MetaData\\ground_truth_archive.shp")

DATABASE =(r"D:\\WORK\\INNOVATION_PROJECTS\\Geomatics_Live_Survey_Plan.gdb")

arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion(J_GT_SURVEYS, DATABASE, "Ground_Truth_Archive")
```

My issue appears to be specific to importing datasets into my geodatabase via arcpy. I can run other arcpy tools through a windows scheduled task once inside the database without any issues. Below is a picture of the action created in the windows scheduled task options to run the script

[image: Windows scheduled task options]

Comment: Does the script run as expected on demand (e.g. not through Windows Task Scheduler)?

Comment: Hi, thanks yes the script runs on demand. I've also discovered that it runs correctly through task scheduler when 'Run Only When user is logged on' is ticked but does not run when 'Run whether user is logged on or not' is ticked. I have administrator privileges and have ticked the 'Run With Highest Privileges' option box and does not work. Any thoughts?

Comment: Is `J` a network location?  Sounds like the task scheduler can't find that mapped drive.

Answer (score 0):

it is recommended to define your workspace

```
import arcpy
arcpy.env.workspace = (r"D:\\WORK\\INNOVATION_PROJECTS\\Geomatics_Live_Survey_Plan.gdb")
```

and then you could add your code:

```
import os 
import arcpy  
import arceditor
import sys
import datetime
J_GT_SURVEYS = (r"J:\\Ground_Truth_Surveys\\MetaData\\ground_truth_archive.shp")
DATABASE =(r"D:\\WORK\\INNOVATION_PROJECTS\\Geomatics_Live_Survey_Plan.gdb")
arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion(J_GT_SURVEYS, DATABASE, "Ground_Truth_Archive")
```